# Sets and Dictionaries in Class Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Trying to find some info on how to use set and dictionaries inside of classes and subclasses. I have an assignment that instructs us to create a class `Country` and a subclass `CountryCatalogue`. Then, in the `def __init__` function create a dictionary called `cDictionary` and `catalogue` (which can be a list, set, or dictionary, I decided to use set but might need to change depending on your suggestions). The issue I'm running into is that when I initialize `cDictionary` and `catalogue` under `class CountryCatalogue(Country):` it tells me none of the functions under it (for example, `__init__()`, `findCountry()`, `addCountry()`, etc) can 'see' the `catalogue` being initialized and give me a "invalid variable" error when I try and access the `catalogue` in those lists, and the same thing happens if I initialize them in the `__init__` function; the other functions can't see it but at least `__init__` works properly.

Unfortunately the class kind of sucks and we were taught all the separate important "themes" for python but not how to use them together.

Example:

```
class CountryCatalogue(Country):
def __init__(self, filename = "", name = "", pop = 0, area = 0, continent = ""):
    cDictionary = {}               #Initializing the cDictionary and catalogue here leads to errors in other functions
    catalogue = []
    super().__init__(name = "",pop = 0,area = 0,continent = "")
    fillcdict  =  open("continent.txt")       #not really important for the problem
    linescdict  =  fillcdict.readlines()[1:]
    for line in linescdict:
        entries1 = line.split(",")
        country = str(entries1[0])
        continentwrong = str(entries1[1])
        entries2 = continentwrong.split ("\n")
        continent = str(entries2[0])
        cDictionary["keywords"] = country
        cDictionary["values"] = continent
    self._continent = continent
    fillcatdict = open(filename)
    linescatalogue  =  fillcatdict.readlines()[1:]
    for line in linescatalogue:
        entries = line.split("|")
        countrydata = str(entries[0])
        populationdata = entries[1]
        areadata = entries[2]
        catalogue.append(countrydata)

def findCountry(self):     #So, when I try and use catalogue in this function I get a 'unresolved reference' note in Pycharm and a "invalid variable' error if I run the problem
    findcountinp = input("Please enter a country name: ")
    if findcountinp in catalogue:
        return self._name+"|"+self._continent+"|"+self._area+"|"+self._population
    else:
        return "Country not found!"
```

Answer (score 0):

`catalogue = []` in `__init__(self, ...)` creates a local variable visible only inside that method whose lifetime ends when the method returns.  Instead do `self.catalogue = []` and then refer to it as `self.catalogue` whenever you use it.  This will make `catalogue` a member of your object rather than a local variable.

Comment: How would I then remove things from the catalogue? 

Catalogue would be a list of all the countries provided in a separate data file. In another function I didn't include in the question I have to ask the user to input a country and then search the catalogue and remove the country that they input.

Comment: `self.catalogue.pop(index)` or `self.catalogue.remove(country)`.  Your design is suspect.  You do realize that it doesn't make sense to have `CountryCatalogue` be a subclass of `Country`, right?  How is a group of countries also a country?  Or if each `Country` is created as a `CountryCatalogue` then the member list `catalogue` will be different for each country.  You will have as many catalogues as countries.

Comment: Well, one of the functions in Country is setPopulationDensity, where you calculate the population density. But then in CountryCatalogue you have the function filterCountriesByPopDensity which instructs: "ask the user to enter the lower bound and upper bound for a population density range and then find all countries that have a population density that falls within the range" Nowhere does it say to calculate population density, it suggests that population density is already calculated (I'm assuming from the Country class) but I dont know how to get a function from one class and use it in another

Comment: There are a few functions in CountryCatalogue that directly reference Country as well, such as "use the default print function from Country" to print whatever

Comment: So if you have some country `c = Country("Finland", pop=3, area=10)` you would access population density by calling `c.getPopulationDensity()`.  Calling that method does not need to happen from a subclass.  If you have further questions, feel free to post them as brand new questions.